# On Save, the foreign key value in child table is empty for REST XML service

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa

This is a REST XML service. On Save, the foreign key value in child table is empty.
The @Id's are using sequence and it works fine. Im not added the sequence generator code here.

```
//Main Entity
------------

@Entity
@Table(name="REQUEST")
public class MsaDisabScreenRequest implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="REQUEST_ID")
    private long requestId; //sequence


    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="msaDisabScreenRequest")
    private Set<ReqDetail> disabilities;

}
```

### Child Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REQ_DETAILS")
public class ReqDetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="MAP_ID")
    private long mapId;  //sequence

    @Column(name="TYPE_ID")
    private long disabilityTypeId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID")
    privateRequest msaDisabScreenRequest;


}
```

This is the dto that I'm using to map.

### //Main Dto

```
@XmlRootElement(name="DisabilityRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MsaDisabScreenRequestDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long requestId; 

    @NotNull
    private Set<DetailDto> disabilities;

}
```

### //Child Dto

```
@XmlRootElement(name="disabilities")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MsaDisabScreenReqDetailDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long mapId; 
    private long disabilityTypeId;

    @XmlTransient
    private RequestDto msaDisabScreenRequest;

}
```

This is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = ApiPath.REQUEST, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/xml"})
    public @ResponseBody ResultDecorator saveScreeningRequest(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDto requestDto) throws Exception {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

save code which is using jpa repository to persist.

Implementation code only added the code releavant to save

```
@Autowired
    private OrikaBeanMapper mapper;

    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    // mapping
    Request request = mapper.map(requestDto,Request.class);
    Request Res = msaRepository.save(request);
```

This is the request payload I'm sending

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<DisabilityRequest>

   <disabilities>
        <disabilityTypeId>9</disabilityTypeId>
    </disabilities>
</DisabilityRequest>
```

Here the requestId is added as empty REQ_DETAILS table. All other entries passed are persisted.

Let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 0):

When fetch type is LAZY, the data set are empty. You can use Fetch type EAGER but its expensive